# How to export child array element to excel in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, laravel-5.5

I'm building an application in `Laravel 5.5`, with `matwebsite/excel` plugin where I'm having an array element to be exported into csv file. I'm able to get the values when I assign single string to key inside an array, but currently I have child array element which is present into the array, which is giving me blank excel sheet once included the same.

Without array elements:

```
public function investor(Request $request)
{
    $record_set = [];
    $tables = json_decode($request->investorTable);
    foreach($tables  as $table)
    {
        $record_set[] = array(
            'schedule' => $table->schedule,
            'Event type' => $table->event_type,
            'Venue' => $table->venue,
            'Nature' => $table->nature,
        );
    }

    return Excel::create('investor', function($excel) use ($record_set) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($record_set) {
            $sheet->fromArray($record_set);
        });
    })->download('csv');
}
```

this is working perfect but I want to place an array element whose `name` key I want to export, I don't know how to implement when I implement it it gives me blank sheet,

```
$record_set[] = array(
    'schedule' => $table->schedule,
    'Company Name' => $table->companyName,
    'Contact Person' => $table->contact_participants,
    'Event type' => $table->event_type,
    'Venue' => $table->venue,
    'Nature' => $table->nature,
);
```

my complete array element is something like this:

[image: export data set]

and the table looks into my html something like this:

[image: tables]

I want exactly same output in excel, help me out with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

Export to Excel5 (xls)

```
Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) {

})->export('xls');

// or
```

Export to Excel2007 (xlsx)

```
->download('xls');
Export to Excel2007 (xlsx)
->export('xlsx');

// or
->download('xlsx');
```

Export to CSV

```
Export to CSV
->export('csv');

// or
->download('csv');
```

Please refer that documentation

http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export

Comment: Did you get my question? I said my export is working fine if I don't use the array child elements, and it gives me blank when I use child array element.